# How do I get the status of the cash drawer back after opening it in NCR 7167 Receipt Printer?

Tags: c#, point-of-sale, thermal-printer, pos

I am using NCR 7167 receipt printer with a cash drawer attached to it. I want to get back the status of the cash drawer as soon as it's opened or closed. I am able to open the cash drawer programmatically. i.e. using the command from the manual. How do I get back the status of the cash drawer when it's opened or closed?? Does anybody know how the **Auto Status Back** thing works in here? If any of you guys know how its done, please help.

Comment: If you need to know then you are doing it wrong.  You never want to close the drawer yourself with human hands in the way, doubtful it is even possible.  You always know when you want to open it, if it is already open then it doesn't matter.

Comment: @HansPassant Hi, so how do I get back the status of the drawer when it opens? Can you teach me how to make the auto status back thing work??

Comment: Please ask a friend or team member to explain my comment to you.

Comment: He only wants the status back, not close the drawer programatically.  Please ask a friend or team member to explain his question to you.

Answer (score -1):

Auto status back functionality is present in many receipt printers or devices that control the cash drawer kickout port.  If you enable ASB, the device will continously send status reports, or send status reports when cash drawer state changes.  In either case, your software must be capable of asynchronously receiving data from the printer.  This often means running a separate thread that monitors the cash drawer. So the problem is less a technical one (you send a command to the printer to enable ASB and that's it), but your software must conceptually be able to handle such data.

Comment: Hi Marc, I did not downvote your answer. Yes I was fiddling and I found out ASB works. Thanks, but can we also close the drawer from the program? I don't find solution for it now.

Comment: No, the drawer can not be closed programmatically.  You can "only" open it and get its status.